# Swift - passing variable with delegate

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delegates

I basically want to pass an array-index but I am getting an error message and I can not get behind the problem.

The index I want to access is inside my `dropDownView` (`didSelectRowAt`).

```
class dropDownView: UIView, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource  {



var dropDownOptions = [String]()

var tableView = UITableView()

var delegate : dropDownProtocol!

var selectedWishlistDelegate: selectedWishlistProtocol!

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray


    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    self.addSubview(tableView)

    tableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return dropDownOptions.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()

    cell.textLabel?.text = dropDownOptions[indexPath.row]
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    self.delegate.dropDownPressed(string: dropDownOptions[indexPath.row])

    self.selectedWishlistDelegate.didSelectWishlist(idx: indexPath.row) // fatal error

    self.tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}

}

//MARK: Protocols

protocol selectedWishlistProtocol {
    func didSelectWishlist(idx: Int)
}
```

To access it inside my `ExampleViewController` I tried this:

```
    extension ExampleViewController: selectedWishlistProtocol{
    func didSelectWishlist(idx: Int) {
        self.selectedWishlistIDX = idx
    }
}
```

Right now I am getting this error:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

Why is `indexPath.row` `nil` ?? It is working fine with the `delegate` right above.

Probably a beginners mistake since I am not too comfortable with `delegates` but I am grateful for every help :)

***Update***

I instantiate my `dropDownView` in my DropDownBtn`-class:

```
class DropDownBtn: UIButton, DropDownProtocol {

func dropDownPressed(string: String) {
    self.setTitle(string, for: .normal)
    self.dismissDropDown()
}

var dropView = DropDownView()

var height = NSLayoutConstraint()


override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray

    dropView = DropDownView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
    dropView.delegate = self
    dropView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
}

override func didMoveToSuperview() {
    self.superview?.addSubview(dropView)
    self.superview?.bringSubviewToFront(dropView)
    dropView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    dropView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    dropView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    height = dropView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0)
}

var isOpen = false
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if isOpen == false {

        isOpen = true

        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate([self.height])

        if self.dropView.tableView.contentSize.height > 150 {
            self.height.constant = 150
        } else {
            self.height.constant = self.dropView.tableView.contentSize.height
        }


        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([self.height])

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.dropView.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.dropView.center.y += self.dropView.frame.height / 2
        }, completion: nil)

    } else {
        isOpen = false

        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate([self.height])
        self.height.constant = 0
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([self.height])
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.dropView.center.y -= self.dropView.frame.height / 2
            self.dropView.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)

    }
}

func dismissDropDown() {
    isOpen = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate([self.height])
    self.height.constant = 0
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([self.height])
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
        self.dropView.center.y -= self.dropView.frame.height / 2
        self.dropView.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: nil)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
}
```

Comment: start class/struct/protocol  names with capital letter

Comment: The problem is that you are not setting `selectedWishlistDelegate` on `dropView` so when `dropView` goes to call it's `selectedWishlistDelegate` it tries to access a value that has not been set yet ( because of the `!` that you added to the end of `selectedWishlistDelegate` )  to solve this problem, adhere to the best practices outlined in my answer and set the `selectedWishlistDelegate` value on `dropView`.

Comment: I already set `selectedWishlistDelegate` inside `dropDownView` ? Sorry might misunderstand you here

Comment: I just added more code to solve your problem but you should also always begin protocols with capital letters as a convention. Also, I don't see where you "set selectedWishlistDelegate inside dropDownView".

Comment: If you add a link to the repo we can take a better look.

Comment: here you go: https://github.com/chriskonnerth/Wishlist

Comment: I just created a pull request against your app a few seconds ago. The changes should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best practices here are to make your `delegate` and `listener` references optional. Here, it appears, you are [force unwrapping](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/sixty/10/4/force-unwrapping) `selectedWishlistDelegate` without having set it first. By using `!` after the declaration `selectedWishlistDelegate` you are asserting that this reference will not be nil, but it seems that it is. This causes a runtime error and crashes your app.

To solve this problem change this:

```
var delegate : dropDownProtocol!

var selectedWishlistDelegate: selectedWishlistProtocol!
```

to this:

```
var delegate : dropDownProtocol?

var selectedWishlistDelegate: selectedWishlistProtocol?
```

and this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    self.delegate.dropDownPressed(string: dropDownOptions[indexPath.row])

    self.selectedWishlistDelegate.didSelectWishlist(idx: indexPath.row) // fatal error

    self.tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

to this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    self.delegate?.dropDownPressed(string: dropDownOptions[indexPath.row])

    self.selectedWishlistDelegate?.didSelectWishlist(idx: indexPath.row) // fatal error

    self.tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

then you need to change:

```
class DropDownBtn: UIButton, DropDownProtocol {
```

to:

```
class DropDownBtn: UIButton, DropDownProtocol, selectedWishlistProtocol {
    func didSelectWishlist(idx: indexPath.row) {
        self.selectedWishlistIDX = idx
    }
```

and finally, you should set the `` so you should change this:

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray

    dropView = DropDownView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
    dropView.delegate = self
    dropView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
}
```

to this:

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {

    super.init(frame: frame)

    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray

    dropView = DropDownView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
    dropView.delegate = self
    dropView.selectedWishlistDelegate = self
    dropView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
}
```

This will protect your app from crashing if you haven't set the `selectedWishlistDelegate` yet and will allow you to test the functionality of your view more easily.

Comment: Did that and like you said, my app is no longer crashing. However that doesn't really solve my problem though as the index is not getting passed

Comment: I've just added some more code that will solve all of your problems but the key here is that you did not set `selectedWishlistDelegate` on `dropView`. You only set `delegate` on `dropView` so when you tried to use `selectedWishlistDelegate` in the `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
` method call, your app crashes because you asserted that  `selectedWishlistDelegate` would not be `nil` but it was `nil` because you didn't set it.

Comment: ah man I really appreciate your help but the code you added didn't change anything :( In your code you added `func didSelectWishlist` in `DropDownBtn` but that has no `selectedWishlistIDX`. I just added `var selectedWishlistIDX` in it but that didn't change anything either

Comment: also, why add another `func didSelectWishlist` ? I did that in my `extension ExampleVC: SelectedWishlistProtocol` . Is something wrong with that maybe?

Comment: I tested it with `print` and it does not go into that function at all

Comment: Well the reason is that whatever object that you set to `SelectedWishlistProtocol` needs to have that method defined. The problem that you are having is that you are not including this line `dropView.selectedWishlistDelegate = self`.

Comment: ok get that. I am just really right now where to include this exactly. Maybe you could have a look at my repo :) Let me know if anythings unclear

Comment: I just made a pull request against your repo with my changes. If you would like some help trying to untangle your code and fix some of your other problems, you can reach me on GitHub.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204358/discussion-between-dieglueckswurst-and-wikipediabrown).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure

```
var selectedWishlistDelegate:SelectedWishlistProtocol!
```

isn't nil , meaning when you instantiate the view you set it

```
let v = DropDownView()
v.selectedWishlistDelegate = // some value
```

Comment: what do I set it to?

Comment: `DropDownView` get's instantiated in my `dropDownBtn`- class that makes it a bit more confusing